# How to calculate win chance ticket in percentage

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to calculate a win chance from buying a freebies ticket in the percentage of each user that has been recorded in the database

here is my freebies table

```
fr_id | user_id
1     | 60
2     | 50
3     | 4
4     | 60
5     | 60
6     | 60
7     | 4
8     | 60
9     | 50
10    | 50
```

the total number of tickets is 10

- **user id 60** have a **5 tickets**
- **user id 50** have a **3 tickets**
- **user 4** have **2 tickets**

so I want to calculate on each user how much win chance they get

for example :

- user 60: 70% win chance
- user 50: 25% win chance
- user 4: 5% win chance

how to calculate it in PHP code based on user id?

```
$win_chance = $database->query("SELECT * FROM freebies WHERE user_id='60'");
echo $win_chance; //example 70%
```

Comment: Well first of all, 5/10 = 50%, 3/10 = 30%, and 2/10 = 20%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next simple query:

```
select 
    sum(user_id = 60) / count(*) as chance
from tickets;
```

[test SQL query](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/499a51964af49baa264f372f22b15e3c/)

Below is PHP implementation:

```
<?php

$user_id = 60;

$query = "select 
    sum(user_id = ?) / count(*) as chance
from tickets;";

// get DB version using PDO
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$user_id]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
printf('Win chance for user %d is %s ' . PHP_EOL, $user_id, $row['chance']);
```

[PHP test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/f74d15a4c43ee7106641c5382a45fe80/php/php8/ff69d66a962419a8eb23895d781c80c0/)

Answer (score 1):

The below should give you the percentage rate of each user

```
with cte as (
select 1 as fr_id, 60 as user_id
union all select 2, 50
union all select 3, 4
union all select 4, 60
union all select 5, 60
union all select 6, 60
union all select 7, 4
union all select 8, 60
union all select 9, 50
union all select 10, 50)

select user_id, 
       cast(count(fr_id) as float)/(select count(*) from cte) * 100 
from cte 
group by user_id;
```